# parseFloat of input value returns NaN

Tags: javascript, user-input, nan, parseint, parsefloat

I'm trying to write a script that dynamically calculates a total from 4 inputs that are editable by the user.

I'm having some trouble when I use *parseFloat* on my input values. They return as `NaN`.

So far, I've tried using `parseInt` instead of `parseFloat`, used `.val()` instead of `.value`, using `name` attributes instead of `id` attributes, and a couple of other things, that I can't remember off hand.

I haven't seen any other answers to similar questions, that have worked for me yet, so if you wouldn't mind taking a look at my code to see where I might've gone wrong, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Calc</title>
<style>
 
</style>   
</head>

<body>
   <table width = "250" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th align="left">A</th>
        <th align="left">B</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rent</td>
        <td id="rent" align="right">
           <input type="text" size="7" value="0" onchange="calc()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Food</td>
        <td id="food" align="right">
           <input type="text" size="7" value="0" onchange="calc()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Entertainment</td>
        <td id="ent" align="right">
           <input type="text" size="7" value="0" onchange="calc()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transportation</td>
        <td id="trans" align="right">
           <input type="text" size="7" value="0" onchange="calc()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Total</th>
        <td id="total" align="right"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <script>
      function calc() {
         var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rent").value);
         var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("food").value);
         var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ent").value);
         var z = parseFloat(document.getElementById("trans").value);
         
         document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=w+x+y+z;
      }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is the id on the TD and not the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were giving your cells (`<td>` tags) `id` attributes, rather than your actual `input` fields.

**Moving the `id` attributes to the `input` elements solves the issue.**

In addition, since your are going to call the `calc` function repeatedly, it would make more sense to just scan the document once to get the references to the elements you are going to want to use over and over.

Lastly, it's best not to hook your HTML elements up to the JavaScript functions that should fire when an event happens in the HTML itself. You can see in my code snippet how I've removed that from the HTML and put it into the JavaScript.

```js
// Wait until the DOM is fully loaded
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  
   // Declare and initialze variable references to needed elements:
   var wElement = document.getElementById("rent");
   var xElement = document.getElementById("food");
   var yElement = document.getElementById("ent");
   var zElement = document.getElementById("trans");

   // Wire elements to event handlers:
   wElement.addEventListener("change", calc);
   xElement.addEventListener("change", calc);
   yElement.addEventListener("change", calc);
   zElement.addEventListener("change", calc);

   // Event handler:
   function calc() {
         var w = parseFloat(wElement.value);
         var x = parseFloat(xElement.value);
         var y = parseFloat(yElement.value);
         var z = parseFloat(zElement.value);
         
         document.getElementById("total").textContent = w + x + y + z;
   } 
});
```

```html
<table width = "250" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th align="left">A</th>
        <th align="left">B</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rent</td>
        <td  align="right">
           <input type="text" id="rent" size="7" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Food</td>
        <td  align="right">
           <input type="text" id="food" size="7" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Entertainment</td>
        <td  align="right">
           <input type="text" id="ent" size="7" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transportation</td>
        <td  align="right">
           <input type="text" id="trans" size="7" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Total</th>
        <td id="total" align="right"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the value of `td`'s when you should target the inputs inside those `td`s, so you could use :

```
var w = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#rent input").value);
var x = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#food input").value);
var y = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#ent input").value);
var z = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#trans input").value);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function calc() {
  var w = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#rent input").value);
  var x = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#food input").value);
  var y = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#ent input").value);
  var z = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#trans input").value);

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=w+x+y+z;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calc</title>
    <style>

    </style>   
  </head>

  <body>
    <table width = "250" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th align="left">A</th>
        <th align="left">B</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rent</td>
        <td id="rent" align="right">
          <input type="text" size="7" value="0" onchange="calc()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Food</td>
        <td id="food" align="right">
          <input type="text" size="7" value="0" onchange="calc()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Entertainment</td>
        <td id="ent" align="right">
          <input type="text" size="7" value="0" onchange="calc()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transportation</td>
        <td id="trans" align="right">
          <input type="text" size="7" value="0" onchange="calc()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Total</th>
        <td id="total" align="right"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```